# PHP How to find the number of day's before the event happen compare to current date

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

How to find the  number of day's before the event happen compare to current date , i having Linux time in my database i am converting the Linux to ordinary time `like 2012-05-28 17:25:43,`

i am tried like this its not working

```
   $sql_sms_transactions = "SELECT MAX(`sendtime`) FROM `sms_transaction`  where customer_id='$customer_id'";

    $result_sms_transactions = mysql_query($sql_sms_transactions);
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_sms_transactions))
{

    $status = $row2['MAX(`sendtime`)'];

    $timestamp2 = $status;


    $ptime= gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp2);

 function time_elapsed_string($ptime)
  {
$etime = time() - $ptime;

if ($etime < 1)
{
    return '0 seconds';
}

$a = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
            30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
            24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
            60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
            60                      =>  'minute',
            1                       =>  'second'
            );

foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
{
    $d = $etime / $secs;
    if ($d >= 1)
    {
        $r = round($d);
        return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
    }
}
     }

}
```

i want to compare this  `2012-05-28 17:25:43` with current date (today) and find out how many days before it happens i want only days,

```
final out put text should be like xx Days Ago
```

Does anyone have a better solution or code thanks.....

Comment: @deceze it's not duplicate also its not calculating days properly,if you know the answer writeme

Comment: How's that not a duplicate? There's a great answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/476

Comment: i tried that codes its shows compare the current date and the date like this (17-06-2012) its shows  0years 16days do you think its write its just 16day

Comment: could show us the code which you tried ?

Comment: i pasted the code above ,it's inside the while loop each time its take date from database and compare the date display the result,unfortunately its not working

Comment: did you tried the answer which deceze linked ?

Comment: i tries its displays like this date like this (17-06-2012) its shows 1years 1days do you think its write its just 16day

Comment: because its just differentiate the 16 and 17

Comment: how did you get the current date ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55746/discussion-between-xavi-and-krishna).

Comment: i am getting like this $timestamp1 = time(); and converting it to ordinary date like this $date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp1);

Comment: `$interval->format('%a')` - there's a difference between *days* as in "3 years, 2 months, 1 day" and *total days*. `'a'` is the *total days*.

Comment: @ thanks for you code if you dont mind can you provide me an example so i can easily understand

Comment: Could you please take a look at chat link for the sample code.

Comment: i am already did that code

Comment: Please RTFM for examples: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: @krishna its not working again

Comment: please continue in chat room.

Comment: chat room is not opening for me it saying some error occurred